# how to render an Html tag from an object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an item :

```
 const obj: any = {
          name: '',
          template: null
        };
```

I inform him of the following elements

```
 obj.name = elt.text;
 obj.template = `<p-chart type="line" [data]="data"></p-chart>`;

 this.list = obj;
```

I would like on the Html page, the obj.template is considered to be a html tag, but it considers it to be text

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 my-3"
   *ngFor="let item of list">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{ item.name }}
    {{ item.template }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Would you have a solution to consider obj.template as Html code and not a string tag ?

Comment: `obj.template` would always be rendered as a string in this case. Why not just use another component.

Comment: I thought I would simply make a list of p-charts and integrate them directly into my object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use the `ngFor` with the object which is not iterable. So it will throw an error.
If you are trying it with the array. If you use the `<div [innerHTML]></div>` It will not render  your `p-chart`. You need to use another component which will conditionally render your template.

Comment: Indeed, the graph is not displayed.

What should you use if you want to load a p-chart list?

ng-for me seemed logical

Comment: You can create another component which will render your p-chart. Pass the value of the object to it.

Comment: I will try with another component, I thought it would have been easier

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.template"></div>
```

Comment: will this evaluate `[data]="data"` as well?

Comment: @Stavm I think angular strips the XSS contained code. https://angular.io/guide/security#xss